# How to find peak of Line Graph in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

As the title says, I'm working with a chart.js chart generated with 5-7 data points, and the graph displays just fine. I need a way to find the coordinates of the peak of the graph. The previous version of this was an excel document where the user would just estimate the peak, and trying to use calculus (regression analysis and derivatives) is giving us a wildly different chart. So I really just need a way to pinpoint the peak as shown on this chart.

Any help is ***greatly*** appreciated.

[image: Picture of my UI and what I'm value I'm looking for]

Comment: This curve is caused by line tension (bezier curve), and doesn't actually represent a datapoint. The "peak" of your data is 137.5 (ish), and could be determined by a `Math.max()` or equivalent on your data. Right now, if you were to get the peak (which could be done somehow) it would likely be a pixel coordinate and not a meaningful point related to your dataset.

Comment: That's what I figured, but my boss insisted that there _must_ be a way, so I had to ask. 

The problem with `Math.max()` is that the value we want is most likely not going to be one of our data points, but somewhere between two of them. But thank you for the help, good to be able to explain to the boss.

Comment: Not a problem. There is a simple enough solution; if you were to set the line's tension to 0, you wouldn't get the curve, and the top-most point would be the peak. But aside from that, it would be a complicated algorithm of converting the point of the highest line (in pixels) to the related value (137.6-ish) as determined by the scale.